# Почему свойство функции не записывается?

Tags: javascript

```js
function work(a, b) {
  console.log(a + b);
}

function spy(func) {
  func.calls = [];

  function f(...args) {
    func.calls.push(args);
    return func(...args);
  }
  return func;
}
work = spy(work);
work(2, 6);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function work(a, b) {
  console.log(a + b);
}

function spy (func) {
  f.calls = [];
  function f(...args){
    f.calls.push(args);
    return func(...args);
  }
  return f;
}
work = spy(work);
work(2, 6);
work(3, 4);
console.log(work.calls);
```

Comment: Спасибо, только я не понял почему нельзя на func добавить свойство? Ведь calls добавляется, а значения не пушатся.

Comment: @RuslanSSS "а значения не пушатся" - Чтобы в массив добавлялись аргументы, должна вызываться функця `f`. Ваш код ее не вызывает.

Comment: Наконец-то я понял, спасибо.